# In PHP, can I programmatically resize an image and add white space?

Tags: php, image-processing, image-manipulation

I've found some similar questions to mine, but none that address my specific situation, so I thought I'd ask.

What I have: A square JPEG, measuring 600px x 600px, that I am getting from an external source.

What I want: To programmatically resize the square to 400x400, and add 75px of white space on each side, making the total final image 550px x 400, with the original square image centered.

I'd be grateful if somebody can point me in the right direction.

Comment: Are you looking to actually *save the file* with these alterations or simply *display them* in a browser?

Comment: I don't know about the white space part, but I do know you can embed some php into the dimensional attributtes of the img.

Comment: Yes, I'll need to save the file.  Should have mentioned that part.

Comment: @nei - You might want to take a look at iMagick or GD (depending on whats installed on your server). Both of those can accomplish what you need. [Read about it here](http://php.net/manual/en/book.image.php)

Comment: @Lix I have both.  Will investigate your link - thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Most PHP installations these days come with the GD image library installed. However, GD lacks a function that does what you want easily and in one step.

If you have access to ImageMagick, you can use this, either from the command line or its PHP API, Imagick. The command-line parameters:

```
convert /path/to/old/image --resize 400x400 --bordercolor white -border 75x0 /path/to/new/image
```

will probably do what you want, and if it's not exactly what you want you can tweak it using the ImageMagick documentation and experimentation. In PHP, this can be carried out with a call to `exec()`, just be careful not to use any user-supplied input to anything in that call as it can be a grave security risk. Alternatively you can use the Imagick PHP extension, which needs to be installed separately, but will allow you to use actual PHP functions instead of a separate command-line call.

Using GD, you need to do a little more work:

```
// Load image from file
$image=imagecreatefromjpeg('/path/to/image.jpg');
// Resize to 400x400
$image=imagescale($image,400,400);
// Create new blank image (defaults to black background)
$new_image=imagecreatetruecolor(550,400);
// Initialize a new color
$white=imagecolorallocate($new_image,255,255,255);
// Fill the newly-created image with white
imagefilledrectangle($new_image,0,0,550,400,$white);
// Embed old image into new image
imagecopy($new_image,$image,75,0,0,0,400,400);
// Write finished image to disk, use quality setting of 85:
imagejpeg($new_image,'/path/to/new/image.jpg',85);
```

I have tested this code with PHP 7.4 but I am not aware of any appreciable differences with other versions.

There is a more concise way of doing this (condense two steps into one) using the `imagecopyresized` function but I prefer not doing that because it doesn't really improve performance much, and the resulting code is less readable because that function has a whopping 10 parameters, always a debugging nightmare.

As you can see, ImageMagick makes this much simpler. However, not everyone has access to it, and as it is a larger, more complex package, it can potentially pose greater security risks, so even if you have root access on the server, you may not wish to install it. Depending on what you are doing, GD can be slightly faster and more lightweight in some circumstances too.

One further warning: using GD will cause the script to load the image into memory *as part of the PHP process* and this memory usage (which can be quite high, as image processing is memory-intensive) will count towards PHP's memory limit, whereas calling ImageMagick separately will start a separate process that will not count towards this limit.

Answer (score -2):

[php.net/manual/en/ref.image.php](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.image.php)

These functions are be able to do exactly what you want, and they are pretty simple to use as well.

Comment: There is no code how this could be done in this answer.

Comment: I am pretty sure GD does not have built in functionality like the OP requested in this question.

Comment: I added an answer explaining how to do what the OP asked, using GD. It is hardly straightforward, but it can be done using a series of function calls that basically create a new image, fill it with white, and then copy the resized image into the new image and save it to disk.